# GORM - Temporarily disable beforeInsert event

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.5

There is a way to temporarily disable the beforeInsert event of a specific Domain Class? I need to execute the following steps:

1. disable the execution of beforeInsert;
2. Execute a kind of saveAs routine in an object;
3. re-enable the execution of beforeInsert.

The saveAs routine executes a deep clone in a specific object and creates a new object with the same data. See this answer to understand the clone: [How can I duplicate a domain object in Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614791/how-can-i-duplicate-a-domain-object-in-grails/17629959#17629959)

**Reason to disable beforeInsert**: Since the object is cloned the code inside beforeInsert doesn't need to be executed when the saveAs routine is executed.

Grails version: 2.5.0

**Update**

I forgot to mention that I want to avoid change my Domain Class to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: Hi @cantoni, didi you find the best solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, @HemãVidal. My solution was avoid use the beforeInsert event. My saveAs routine is much more important than the code executed in beforeInsert.

Comment: I think that is a concept issue:
If a .save() method works different in some situations, the controllers must do this action and remove this behavior from domain.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a transient Boolean field in the domain class and based on the value of this field you can run your beforeInsert code e.g;

```
class Person{

Boolean runBeforeInsert = true

static transients = ['runBeforeInsert']

def beforeInsert(){
    if(runBeforeInsert){
         SOME CODE .....
    }
}
}
```

This might not be the best solution but it's one of the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Uday. That is a possible solution, but I'm searching a non-invasive solution. I want to avoid change my domain class. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @cantoni IMO there is no other way around, and this might be the less invasive method.